# fusion::vector + fusion::push_back = fusion::vector?

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

I typedef a vector with two elements. Then I push_back into it an other element and expect what result type is also a vector. But that's not so.

Example:

```
typedef boost::fusion::vector<int, double> vec1;
typedef boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<vec1, std::string> vec2;
//boost::is_same<vec2, boost::fusion::vector<int, double, std::string>>::value == false
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/361492801eebe24cc5679a1e899a5240

What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've aliased the `push_back` itself as `vec2`. You need to use

```
typedef boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<vec1, std::string>::type vec2;
```

But keep in mind that the type might still not be the same, Fusion algorithms are not required to preserve the type (and since `push_back` function is supposed to return a lazy view, then `vec2` will most likely be some view type). The only guarantee is that `vec2` will be ["A model of Forward Sequence."](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/metafunctions/push_back.html).

Comment: Please tell me, how can I initialize the object of type vec2?

Comment: vec2 v(33, .14, "string"); link: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6d35d3211640ee62174dced31a28d937

Comment: @niXman: `vec2 v(boost::fusion::push_back(vec1(33, .14), "string"));` I guess. I don't really use Fusion.

Comment: Thanks. I`ve expected a more usability.

Comment: You can use as_vector to force the return type of the push_back to act as a vector properly